# Text input and output it on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering if I can create a text input where users can type some text and then immediately display them on page, same as twitter. I know about alert window or prompt window but I need something different, a text input on website.

Hope it can be done in JavaScript.

Comment: Please be more descriptive in what you are trying to ask

Comment: When you say *"users can type some text and then immediately display them on page"* Do you mean like a preview of what the client's post will look like before submitting?

Comment: Im sorry, I mean just like twitter or facebook work, people type text, hit submit and text immediately displays on a page

Answer (score 2):

Use **.keyup() for the input field** then replace the content of the output div.

```js
$(".div-input").keyup(function() {
  $(".output").html($(this).val());
});
```

```css
.output {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="div-input" />

<div class="output">
</div>
```

If you want to display the input on submit, you could **attach a .submit() event on a form tag** then use **appendTo on the div** if you want to insert multiple elements;

```js
$(".form-input").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var value = $(".div-input").val();

  $("<div class='outputs'>" + value + "</div>").appendTo($(".output"));
});
```

```css
.output {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.outputs {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 2em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-input">
  <input class="div-input">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<div class="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thats what I was looking for, but page displays text as user type, can I somehow add option so the users can first press enter or even better click submit and then display it on page

Comment: @YoungSquad I updated the code, I added another snippet that has the submit you're looking for.

Comment: Man code is perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: No problem @YoungSquad , good luck with the project. Also read the other answers as my code uses jquery and not native javascript.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this to show your text anywhere on page

```
  <input id="input-name" oninput="outputname.value = this.value">
  <output id="outputname" name="outputname" for="input-name"></output>
```

You can test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tejsoft/dtj45pk6/)

Comment: Classy solution. Please put in a jsfiddle or a code snippet to show a working version.

Answer (score 1):

If you add an eventlistener to the input, you can use that to change the text in your output area on the page. Like this:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');
const output = document.getElementById('output');
input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  output.innerHTML = input.value;
});
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
<input type="text" id="input">
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<p>Input:</p><input id="input" type="text">
<p>Output:<span id="output"></span></p>
```

Javascript:

```
// Function To Select Element

function $(element) {
  return document.querySelector(element);
}

// We will get the input when calling this function
function getInput() {
  return $('#input').value;
}

// The output will be displayed
function output() {
   $('#output').innerHTML = getInput();
}

// This function will start our code
 function init() {
   output();
 }

// On keyup our code will initiate

$('#input').addEventListener('keyup', init);
```

You can test it here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ReyGaO?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

People are downvoting you because this can be done with **very basic JavaScript**, and questions like this are very unusual because anyone doing a basic JavaScipt course will probably be able to do this.

Theoretically speaking: you can put an input element and a button on the html page, plus an empty div. **You can set an event for the button or even for the input for live updating while typing, and write an event handler function to change the content of the empty div.** You can either set its content or add a new child to it, so that the previous content still remains.

Practical example: (The code below is live at https://codepen.io/bradib0y/pen/YJLGrb )

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to add a new post.</p>

<input id="NewPostField" type="text" value="Some text">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Add new post</button>

<div id="Posts"></div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var NewPostField = document.getElementById("NewPostField");
    var newPost = document.createElement("p");

    newPost.innerHTML = NewPostField.value;

    var Posts = document.getElementById("Posts");
    Posts.appendChild(newPost);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know and Im sorry but I couldn’t find the answer, this helped, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by this

```
<input id="mainInput" oninput="output.value = this.value">
<output id="output" name="output" for="input-name"></output>
```

[click here to view in jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/zkLs9h2a/5/)